# HTTP::Request replacing underscores with hyphens in headers

Tags: perl, http, header

When specifying custom header containing underscores using `HTTP::Request` from `LWP::UserAgent`, the underscores are changed to hyphens:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $rq = HTTP::Request->new("GET", "http://cpan.org");
$rq->header("X-FOO_BAR", "xyzzy");
print $rq->as_string;
```

outputs:

```
GET http://cpan.org
X-FOO-BAR: xyzzy
```

Is there a way to turn this behavior off?

- perl v5.26.2
- LWP:UserAgent 1.9601
- linux 4.17.8-1-ARCH

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try naming the header with a leading `:`, as per the documentation in [HTTP::Headers](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers#NON-CANONICALIZED-FIELD-NAMES) under "NON-CANONICALIZED FIELD NAMES":

> The header field name spelling is normally canonicalized including the '_' to '-' translation. There are some application where this is not appropriate. Prefixing field names with ':' allow you to force a specific spelling.

Comment: Yup, I was just about to post ... :)  tested (v5.16)

Comment: That's a dusty corner of CPAN that I didn't know about.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too while trying to write out a location in a pages header via `CGI::Session`. I fixed it by replacing the underscore with `%5f` and it worked for me. In your case this might work:

```
$rq->header('X-FOO%5fBAR', "xyzzy");
```